# Function gets not executed in Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a component where I want to dispatch a Redux action through a function. What I do not understand is, the function is not executed. A `console.log()` right before and after the functioncall `bar()` gets logged, but when I try to `console.log()` from the function `bar()`, that has no effect what so ever... Why is that?

```
// Foo.js
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import React from 'react';
import { bar } from './actions';

const Foo = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log('I get logged');
        bar();
    console.log('I get logged too');
    }, [])

    return <Whatever> ... </Whatever>
};


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({
        bar,
    }, dispatch)
};

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const { ... } = state
    return {
        ...: ...
    }
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Foo);




// actions.js
export const bar = () => async dispatch => {
    console.log('I do not get logged');
    await ... 
    dispatch({ type: ..., ... });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `bar` at this point references your unbound action creator, not the one from `connect`. You would have to use `props.bar` to get that. But you should not.

Generally, you should not use `connect` with function components, but the `useDispatch` and `useSelector` [react-redux hooks instead](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks).

So it should look like

```js
const Foo = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log('I get logged');
        dispatch(bar());
    console.log('I get logged too');
    }, [dispatch])

    return <Whatever> ... </Whatever>
};
```

without any use of `connect` anywhere.